# Where are the node.js app files installed in an AWS elastic beanstalk instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In an AWS elasticbeanstalk instance, where are the node.js app files deployed to?  I wanted to ssh to the machine and debug some issues and wanted to check that the files were deployed correctly.  I checked /var/ but didn't see an app directory there.

Answer (score 4):

It's in the `/tmp/deployment/application` folder during deployment and then it is moved to `/var/app/current`.

The node logs are in `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`